# Referring to specific record's Controls on subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subform which makes a lot of use of conditional formatting to grey-out cells which cannot contain data, and highlight cells which have been adjusted by the user. The subform is a Datasheet.

This all works fine, except for the lag in applying the formatting, which sometimes even won't update until the user mouses over the cells.

What I would like to try is applying the formatting in VBA, rather than using the in-built conditional formatting, as I would rather the form takes a couple of seconds longer to load but with all formatting applied once it does, than to have the delay I'm currently getting.

So what I'm stuck on, is how to tie back a control on the subform to a specific record in the view that's populating it. For example, I can use the following code:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    MsgBox ctrl.Name & " : " & ctrl.Value
Next ctrl
```

Which might display, for instance, "RowNumber : 010", so I could identify what record that control relates to, but when it says "TotalUSD : 1,234,567.89", I would have no way of knowing which record that related to, and therefore whether or not formatting should be applied.

Is there a better way of doing this, I guess ideally by being able to link each `ctrl` to its corresponding record in the `Form.Recordset`?

**UPDATE**

Below screenshot shows the conditional formatting as it is currently implemented, and what I am trying to achieve using VBA instead of conditional formatting.
[image]

Comment: Is the subform a continuous form?

Comment: No, it's a Datasheet form

Comment: I do not think you can format cells in your datasheet view. Can you add a picture of your userform with annotations what you want to achieve?

Comment: Screenshot added - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not have in depth information about your implementation so here is a general suggestion that I have used in my implementations.

You should add some kind of distinguishing column to your table. For example I once had a form that showed projects and employees. The distinguishing column contained a boolean value "True" for each project, "False" for each employee. Based on that information I was able to format accordingly.

My suggestion: Add an integer distinguishing column to your recordset table. The value "0" would be a plain column, "1" would be for greyed out, "2" for user input.

In the Form_Load Event you would have to iterate through all your controls and set the formatting.

Comment: I actually have the info I need - there's an additional column in the view (which isn't displayed) for each column with a boolean value whether it's been adjusted, which is how the conditional formatting is appiled. Additionally, cells which aren't completed have a value of '|NO_DATA|'. So my question is really how do I iterate through the controls, and for each one be able to reference other columns within that row/record?

Comment: I am a little bit out of my element because I've worked extensivley on continuous form but never on datasheet forms. On continous forms you cannot do what you describe. It is not possible because for every column you only have one control. If you change one control you change the whole columns. That is why you can only use conditional formatting. Isn't it the same for the datasheet view?

Comment: Thanks - I believe you are correct and unfortunately it cannot be done this way, so will have to live with the slow updating of the conditional formatting